# Can I export a list of columns?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata, export

I have about 125 custom columns that I want to use on a different SharePoint site. Is there a way to do that without re-entering all the column definitions? In a perfect world, I could do some sort of XML output, then re-import that to the new site. However, the world's not perfect (as far as I know, at least), and I'm trying to gauge how much work I have ahead of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio 2010 it is possible to generate the XML per field or list
   by using the Server Explorer Window after creating a new SharePoint
   site connection.
2. Also Waldek M. has a tool called ImTech Fields Explorer (http://imtech.codeplex.com/releases/view/20753) that would allow export of fields as XML

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 2):

You can save a list as a template with content, save the template locally and upload it to another site collection to provision new lists off of.

I am wondering though if the managed metadata columns operate like Lookup columns when exported, they lose their values.  We're just in the process of upgrading our environment to 2010 so I can't confirm that theory.

Comment: Saving as a list template is the way to go.  You would just add the template to your new site and create a new list from the template.